# Cant remove ? and anything after ? with PHP

Tags: php, html, url

My URL is structured like this **www.example.co.uk/dynamicpage/page?gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx**

I am trying to remove everything after **www.example.co.uk/dynamicpage/page**

I have tried the following

```
$data = explode('?',$data); $data = $data[0];
```

and also tried using **str_replace** with no luck.

I have been trying other ways that people have suggested to a similar issues I am having but it seems like what ever I do it just ignores everything after **?**

**Edit**

dynamicpage will pull a city/town name off my database based on what is typed into the url so example www.example.co.uk/london the dynamic page will display content for London. **www.example.co.uk/london/page** should also show content for London which it does, but not with **?gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx** it just displays the page without content for London and just displays the standard content I have.

**Updated Code**

```
$data = "http://example.co.uk/dynamicpage/page?gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx"; 
$url_arr = parse_url($data); print_r($url_arr);
```

**Returns**

```
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => example.co.uk [path] => /dynamicpage/page [query] => gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx )
```

**Edit**

Problem solved with htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "gclid=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Comment: `var_dump($data)` gives back what?

Comment: You explode is fine. Are you sure your `$data` variable is actually what you think it is before the explode?

Comment: what are you getting in result?

Comment: Returns string(5) "london"

Comment: @MarlinDOODOO so there is no `?` in `$data`..

Comment: show the complete example. because you are getting london from somewhere else

Comment: after your edit, i think u need to use `parse_url()` method ,

Comment: @MarlinDOODOO doesnt the update have everything you need? Put the `scheme`, `host`, and `path` together.. or exclude `scheme` if you dont care about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use htaccess to rewrite url

gclid is google tag manager I believe.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "gclid=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Comment: Worked !!! thank you. I had to place above all my other htaccess rewrites to work though.

Answer (score 4):

Unclear why your way doesn't work but probably a cleaner way to do this would be `parse_url`.

```
$parts = parse_url('www.example.co.uk/dynamicpage/page?gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx');
echo $parts['path'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from other suggestions above, you can also remove it with a regex:

```php
$url = preg_replace('/\?.+$/', '', $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = strtok($url, '?');
```

`$url` is your `www.example.co.ukdynamic/page/page?gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx`

And after `strtok` it's `www.example.co.uk/dynamicpage/page`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get actual URL without query string, then you can use [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
<?php
$data = "www.example.co.uk/dynamicpage/page?gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx";
$url_arr = parse_url($data);
print_r($url_arr);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( 
    [path] => www.example.co.uk/dynamicpage/page 
    [query] => gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx 
    )
```

According to [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), `parse_url()` will return you all component of your URL, so you can find the right path.

Comment: dynamicpage will be different everytime though

Comment: @MarlinDOODOO: parse_url will work , first of all make it dynamic your url and then use it in parse_url method

Comment: are you talking about london? do you want to remove london? @MarlinDOODOO

Comment: No the ? after page still shows in url but in the result that is returned it is removed but the gclid=Cj0KCQ877xx remains

Comment: @MarlinDOODOO: can u please update your question with updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `substr` function:

```
$data = substr($data, 0, strpos($data, "?"));
```

In this way you get the string from the start to the index of the first occurrance of "?" character.